# Dynamic %%writefile in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a variable that holds the contents of a file I'd like to write in Jupyter using `%%writefile`. However, only the cell magic line accepts variables, e.g. `%%writefile $FILE_NAME`. Is there a way to make the contents dynamic, too, i.e. something like this?

```
%%writefile some.file
${variable_that_holds_contents_of_file}
```

The cell magic `%save some.file variable` does it in a similar way, but it always creates a `.py` file and that's not what I want in my use case. It's a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is similar to yours, `%%writefile` will not interpret variables.

If you want a handy one liner for printing a variable to a file you can use `print`:

```py
somejson = """{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}"""

print(somejson, file=open('output.json', 'a'))
```